# jQuery phone number validation allow spaces, minimum of 8 digits

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-validate, phone-number

How can I allow spaces within an a numbers only validation, with a minimum of 8 digits?
Phone numbers are much easier to type in when spaces are allowed. e.g. 0400 123 456, 9699 1234.

Here's my code so far, I've only got the minimum 8 digits validation working:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod(
  "phone",
  function(phone_number, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^\d{8}$/.test(phone_number);
  },
    "Please enter numbers only"
);
```

Comment: Hi, Found this post while searching for an answer to a similar question.  Having never used addMethod to create a custom validation rule, where in the document flow do you specify the custom rule?  And how then to you call it from the rules section of your validate function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the space before validating:

```
return this.optional(element) || /^\d{8,}$/.test(phone_number.replace(/\s/g, ''));
```

This way you retain the space

Comment: Thanks that works, but I want a minimum of 8 numbers, some phone numbers will have 10 digits. How can I make sure the number of digits is greater than 8?

Comment: @JV10 just add a comma after `8` inside the curly braces :), edited my answer per your comment

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to just remove the spaces from the `phone_number` before validating.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod(
  "phone",
  function(phone_number, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^\d{8}$/ *$/.test(phone_number.replace(/\s/g, ""));
  },
    "Please enter numbers only"
);
```

Comment: I'd prefer to keep the spaces as when the form is submitted it will be easier for the recipient to read.